# How to assign varible value to gridview textbox from javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I know this question is asking previously but i don't get any solution from that.

I have grid-view and i want to calculate total amount and assign it in another textbox in same row. calculation is working perfect but i am unable to assign output value to next TextBox `Tol_Txt`.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function CalculateTotal() {
                var grid = document.getElementById("<%= Grid_Delivery_Record.ClientID%>");

                for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
                    var rate = $("input[id*=Qty_Txt]");
                    var qty = $("input[id*=Rate_Txt]");

                    var totalamount = rate[i].value * qty[i].value; //--- Calculate totalamount fine

                    $("input[id*=Tol_Txt]") = totalamount[i].value;   //--- Unable to assign totalamount in Gridview TextBox
                    document.getElementById("Tol_Txt").value = totalamount;   //--also tried this
                    document.getElementById("Tol_Txt").innerHTML= totalamount;   //--also tried this
                }
            }
        </script>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<td>
                        <input name="ctl00$cphpagebody$Grid_Delivery_Record$ctl02$Qty_Txt" type="text" id="cphpagebody_Grid_Delivery_Record_Qty_Txt_0" OnKeyUp="CalculateTotal();" placeholder="Qty...." style="font-size:Small;" />
                    </td><td>
                        <input name="ctl00$cphpagebody$Grid_Delivery_Record$ctl02$Rate_Txt" type="text" id="cphpagebody_Grid_Delivery_Record_Rate_Txt_0" OnKeyUp="CalculateTotal()" placeholder="Rate...." style="font-size:Small;" />
                    </td><td>
                        <input name="ctl00$cphpagebody$Grid_Delivery_Record$ctl02$Tol_Txt" type="text" id="cphpagebody_Grid_Delivery_Record_Tol_Txt_0" style="font-size:Small;" />
                    </td>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does "unable to" mean? Do you get an error? Unexpected behaviour? Perhaps there's simply no input with that ID...we can't tell without seeing the HTML being generated by your application. One thing though...if you're saying you want to put it in a textbox _in the same row_...this implies you will have a "total" textbox in each separate row. Therefore, code which tries to select it by ID cannot work - in each row the box will have a different ID, because element IDs in JavaScript must be unique to each element (or else, by definition, it's not an ID any more!)

Comment: Did you inspect the HTML and check the ID's of the TextBoxes?

Comment: Yes i also debug JavaScript but not giving any error.

Comment: I post my HTML code also. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I understand what you want to say But dont know what should i do for correct output?

Comment: @VDWWD what should i do for correct output.

Comment: Use the correct textboxes

Comment: @VDWWD Text boxes are correct. Please see my HTML code.

Comment: If everything is correct, then where is textbox `Tol_Txt`? And you assign a value `$("input[id*=Tol_Txt]").val(totalamount[i].value)`

Comment: @VDWWD Third textbox is `Tol_Txt`. and All textboxes are inside of Gridview. so in HTML it's id is `cphpagebody_Grid_Delivery_Record_Tol_Txt_0` please see my HTML code.